# why jinja doesn't work in my python web project and it just prints whatever I write?

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I'm a novice programmer, I'm following a course that uses jinja to run part of the python code inside html, I tried my best and it worked exactly like the tutorial, but for me {} It doesn't work and it just prints whatever I write
What is the problem with my work? Is there anything I should add to the project that I didn't?

This is my html code, I highlighted the jinja code in red]
[image]

and this is my python code
[image]

and finally this is my output (i just get a {{job}} in this page, i highlighted that above the mouse icon)
[image]

I would be grateful if you could help me

I imported the jinja file into the python file, but I didn't get an answer, and I searched the net, but there was still no answer :/

Comment: Please (re)read ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your post accordingly. Don't show pictures of text, _show that text_ instead. And if the text is code, show the [mcve] form of that code.

Comment: try pointing your browser to http://localhost:$PORT/ not http://localhost:$PORT/flaskProject/templates/home.html